# How to create new column by using index value in R

Tags: r

please help me with this data

Here is my raw data

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
   vehicle_id                  location           time     for_hire_light
   <chr>                       <chr>              <chr>             <dbl>
 1 zzJcCfa6nuUF9A02Sud5fASxowM 100.50457_13.90834 05:19:37              0
 2 zzJcCfa6nuUF9A02Sud5fASxowM 100.51297_13.91534 05:21:37              0
 3 zzJcCfa6nuUF9A02Sud5fASxowM 100.51323_13.91548 05:22:37              0
 4 zzJcCfa6nuUF9A02Sud5fASxowM 100.50572_13.90243 05:24:37              0
 5 zzJcCfa6nuUF9A02Sud5fASxowM 100.50717_13.8986  05:25:37              0
 6 zzJcCfa6nuUF9A02Sud5fASxowM 100.50979_13.89154 05:26:37              0
 7 zzJcCfa6nuUF9A02Sud5fASxowM 100.51099_13.88835 05:28:37              0
 8 /+bx80f3gOoPMoFBsS+3xX6jpi8 100.6657_13.90103  22:41:30              1
 9 /+bx80f3gOoPMoFBsS+3xX6jpi8 100.66742_13.90093 22:42:30              1
10 /+bx80f3gOoPMoFBsS+3xX6jpi8 100.66916_13.90055 22:44:30              1
```

```
my.df <- structure(list(vehicle_id = c("zzJcCfa6nuUF9A02Sud5fASxowM","zzJcCfa6nuUF9A02Sud5fASxowM", "zzJcCfa6nuUF9A02Sud5fASxowM","zzJcCfa6nuUF9A02Sud5fASxowM", "zzJcCfa6nuUF9A02Sud5fASxowM","zzJcCfa6nuUF9A02Sud5fASxowM", "zzJcCfa6nuUF9A02Sud5fASxowM","/+bx80f3gOoPMoFBsS+3xX6jpi8", "/+bx80f3gOoPMoFBsS+3xX6jpi8","/+bx80f3gOoPMoFBsS+3xX6jpi8"), location = c("100.50457_13.90834","100.51297_13.91534", "100.51323_13.91548", "100.50572_13.90243","100.50717_13.8986", "100.50979_13.89154", "100.51099_13.88835","100.6657_13.90103", "100.66742_13.90093", "100.66916_13.90055"), time = c("05:19:37", "05:21:37", "05:22:37", "05:24:37", "05:25:37","05:26:37", "05:28:37", "22:41:30", "22:42:30", "22:44:30"),for_hire_light = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA,-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

From the data above, I created trips based on vehicle and time like this;

I use `data.table` `rleid`  to get a unique group number for every trip and select the first and last location and times. Here is my code

```
library(dplyr)

my.df %>%
  group_by(grp = data.table::rleid(for_hire_light)) %>%
  summarise(start_location = first(location), 
            end_location = last(location), 
            start_time = first(time), 
            end_time = last(time), 
            for_hire_light = first(for_hire_light)) %>%
  filter(for_hire_light == 0) %>%
  select(-for_hire_light, -grp) %>%
  mutate(trip_id = row_number(), .before = 1) -> result

result
```

And this is my result.

```
This is what the sample looks like:
# A tibble: 10 x 5
   trip_id start_location     end_location       start_time end_time 
     <int> <chr>              <chr>              <chr>      <chr>   
 1       1 13.90834,100.50457 13.84868,100.63194 05:19:37   23:26:42
 2       2 13.6753,100.63453  13.65828,100.71631 00:05:24   00:41:14
 3       3 13.66348,100.71868 13.65258,100.71571 03:49:54   03:57:52
 4       4 13.63345,100.71102 13.63349,100.71096 04:14:52   04:53:52
 5       5 13.59653,100.70172 13.63433,100.71101 05:01:52   05:36:52
 6       6 13.57542,100.79453 13.59612,100.74922 05:57:11   06:15:52
 7       7 13.60123,100.71091 13.63241,100.71297 06:21:52   06:33:52
 8   43875 13.94582,100.735   13.95905,100.62037 19:28:51   20:28:30
 9   43876 14.01229,100.66908 13.98712,100.61631 20:58:30   21:23:30
10   43877 13.79245,100.70217 13.90366,100.66788 22:09:30   22:40:30
```

```
result <- structure(list(trip_id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 43875L,43876L, 43877L), start_location = c("13.90834,100.50457", "13.6753,100.63453","13.66348,100.71868", "13.63345,100.71102", "13.59653,100.70172","13.57542,100.79453", "13.60123,100.71091", "13.94582,100.735","14.01229,100.66908", "13.79245,100.70217"), end_location = c("13.84868,100.63194","13.65828,100.71631", "13.65258,100.71571", "13.63349,100.71096","13.63433,100.71101", "13.59612,100.74922", "13.63241,100.71297","13.95905,100.62037", "13.98712,100.61631", "13.90366,100.66788"), start_time = c("05:19:37", "00:05:24", "03:49:54", "04:14:52","05:01:52", "05:57:11", "06:21:52", "19:28:51", "20:58:30", "22:09:30"), end_time = c("23:26:42", "00:41:14", "03:57:52", "04:53:52","05:36:52", "06:15:52", "06:33:52", "20:28:30", "21:23:30", "22:40:30")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

My question is I want in each tip id has vehicle id's column based on raw data.
Thus, my expected output is

```
# A tibble: 10 x 5
trip_id start_location     end_location       start_time end_time     from_vehicle_id
     <int> <chr>              <chr>              <chr>      <chr>       <chr>
 1       1 13.90834,100.50457 13.84868,100.63194 05:19:37   23:26:42  zzJcCfa6nuUF9A02Sud5fASxowM
 2       2 13.6753,100.63453  13.65828,100.71631 00:05:24   00:41:14  zzJcCfa6nuUF9A02Sud5fASxowM
 3       3 13.66348,100.71868 13.65258,100.71571 03:49:54   03:57:52  zzJcCfa6nuUF9A02Sud5fASxowM
 4       4 13.63345,100.71102 13.63349,100.71096 04:14:52   04:53:52  zzJcCfa6nuUF9A02Sud5fASxowM
 5       5 13.59653,100.70172 13.63433,100.71101 05:01:52   05:36:52  zzLYPcDONaA8lLF2aJYFKnoRDQ4
 6       6 13.57542,100.79453 13.59612,100.74922 05:57:11   06:15:52  zzLYPcDONaA8lLF2aJYFKnoRDQ4
 7       7 13.60123,100.71091 13.63241,100.71297 06:21:52   06:33:52  /+bx80f3gOoPMoFBsS+3xX6jpi8
 8   43875 13.94582,100.735   13.95905,100.62037 19:28:51   20:28:30  /+bx80f3gOoPMoFBsS+3xX6jpi8
 9   43876 14.01229,100.66908 13.98712,100.61631 20:58:30   21:23:30  /+bx80f3gOoPMoFBsS+3xX6jpi8
10   43877 13.79245,100.70217 13.90366,100.66788 22:09:30   22:40:30  /+bx80f3gOoPMoFBsS+3xX6jpi8
```

Which package and function should be applied? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is not completely reproducible though this should help

```
my.df %>%
  group_by(grp = data.table::rleid(for_hire_light)) %>%
  summarise(start_location = first(location), 
            end_location = last(location), 
            start_time = first(time), 
            end_time = last(time), 
            for_hire_light = first(for_hire_light),
            from_vehicle_id = first(vehicle_id)) %>%
  filter(for_hire_light == 0) %>%
  select(-for_hire_light, -grp) %>%
  mutate(trip_id = row_number(), .before = 1) -> result

result
# A tibble: 1 x 6
  trip_id start_location     end_location       start_time end_time from_vehicle_id            
    <int> <chr>              <chr>              <chr>      <chr>    <chr>                      
1       1 100.50457_13.90834 100.51099_13.88835 05:19:37   05:28:37 zzJcCfa6nuUF9A02Sud5fASxowM
```

Still It is advised that you should include `vhicle_id` while creating `trip_id` itself.  This will eliminate same `for hire status` consecutively but for different vehicle. something like this.

```
my.df %>%
  group_by(grp = data.table::rleid(for_hire_light, vehicle_id), vehicle_id) %>%
  summarise(start_location = first(location), 
            end_location = last(location), 
            start_time = first(time), 
            end_time = last(time), 
            for_hire_light = first(for_hire_light)) %>%
  filter(for_hire_light == 0) %>%
  select(-for_hire_light, -grp) %>%
  mutate(trip_id = row_number(), .before = 1)
# A tibble: 1 x 7
# Groups:   grp [1]
  trip_id   grp vehicle_id                  start_location     end_location       start_time end_time
    <int> <int> <chr>                       <chr>              <chr>              <chr>      <chr>   
1       1     1 zzJcCfa6nuUF9A02Sud5fASxowM 100.50457_13.90834 100.51099_13.88835 05:19:37   05:28:37
```